# Проблема в отображении оси, содержащей множество float точек на графике

Tags: python, matplotlib

столкнулся с тем, что при рисовании ось забивается точками, которые потом просто становятся не на свои места. То есть для одного графика может быть 0.1,0.2 и так до 1.0, а другой рисунок на этом же графике, имеющий такие же координаты, нарисуется выше по своим же координатам, то есть на оси к существующим 0.1 - 1.0 выше добавится такой же повтор. На картинке ниже видно, как они располагаются. Данные проверял по переменным, все приходит верно и верно записывается в свои списки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def draw(itterTimer, massiveCount,itterThreadTimer,pyramidTimmer, pyramidThreadTimer):
    itterT = len(itterThreadTimer)/len(massiveCount)
    itterThreadTimer = split(itterThreadTimer, itterT)
    massiveCount = np.array(list(map(int, massiveCount)))
    itterP = len(pyramidThreadTimer)/len(massiveCount)
    pyramidThreadTimer = split(pyramidThreadTimer,  itterP)
    itterTimer = np.array(list(map(float, itterTimer)))
    pyramidTimmer = np.array(list(map(float, pyramidTimmer)))
    for i in range(int(itterT)):
        plt.plot(massiveCount,  (np.array(pyramidThreadTimer[i])), label = "Пиромидальный многопоточный "+ str(2**i))
    plt.plot(massiveCount, itterTimer, label = "Итеративный")
    plt.plot(massiveCount, pyramidTimmer, label = "Пирамидальный однопоточный")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: И кстати, pyramidTimer имеет другие координаты совсем, хотя ему приходят верные, он рисует по другим.(его коорды начинаются с 0.0006), в то время как оси графика графика начинаются с 0.054

Comment: Зачем вы привели данные скриншотом? Что нам с ним делать? Данные приведите текстом, а скрином покажите свой график.

Comment: Это был скриншот проблемной оси графика, но я кажется уже понял в чем ошибка. Список, который туда подается является списком строк, и, вероятно, из-за этого происходит вот это.